# Using join with an iterator and a String function

Tags: java, java-8

Suppose I have an `Iterator<Class1>` object.  `Class1` provides a method `stringFunction()` that returns a `String`.

Is there a way to use `String.join` in a way that calls `stringFunction()` on every `Class1` returned by the iterator, and concatenates the function results separated by a delimiter?

There's a `String.join` overload that takes an `Iterable<CharSequence>`; is it possible to create one from the `Iterator<Class1>` and the `stringFunction`, so that `join` can use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about using

- `streamOfCharSequence.collect(Collectors.joining(delimiter))`

instead of `String.join(delimiter, Iterable<CharSequence>`.

You can try something like

```
String result = StreamSupport
        .stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator,
                Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
        .map(e -> e.stringFunction()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Comment: Yes, that's better.  Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. If you are able to get stream then skip whole calling iterator `StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, Spliterator.ORDERED), false)` and just use `stream().map(e -> e.stringFunction()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))`.

Answer (score 4):

Using Guava, you should be able to do something like this:

```
Iterator<Class1> iter = ...
String result = Joiner.on("//").join(Iterators.transform(iter, x -> x.stringFunction()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works, but seems a little clunky.

```
Iterator<Class1> iterator = ...;

Iterator<CharSequence> funcIterator = 
  StreamSupport.stream(
    Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
  .map(x -> (CharSequence)x.stringFunction())
  .iterator();

String result = String.join("//", () -> funcIterator);
```

It doesn't work to create an `Iterator<String>` because `join` doesn't
accept it; thus it's necessary to declare the type as
`Iterator<CharSequence>`, and also to cast the `String` to a
`CharSequence` in the lambda.  The syntax `() -> idIterator` works for
creating an `Iterable` whose iterator is the given iterator.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: this should be part of question.. isn't it ?

Comment: Depends on how you look at it, I guess ... the original question is the one I was trying to find an answer for, and I found one, and I'm hoping the answer will help someone else.  But I'm still hoping there's a simpler answer.